# $\phi(n)=\frac{2n}{5}$ how do I find the number of solutions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm not really all too sure how to approach this problem, any help would be much appreciated. (Specifically talking about #4)

[image]

Comment: For part 1, $2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 = 210.$  If $m,n$ relatively prime, then $\phi(mn) = \phi(m) \times \phi(n).$  Also, for $p$ prime, $\phi(p) = (p-1)$.

Comment: You need to show your effort, what have you done ... anything!

Answer (score 1):

I assume, it is Euler Totient.

$$\frac{2n}{5}=n(1-\frac 12)(1-\frac 15)$$

A solution will be of the form  $$n= 2^p\times5^q$$

There are many many solutions.